# Font-lock for strings messes up non-code buffers

Tags: magit, font-lock

In Magit buffers, or helm-swoop, an unclosed double quote enables the string highlighting for the rest of the buffer (until another quote is found). This is how it looks like:

[image]

Because of that, I also lose the green/red highlighting of added/removed lines in Magit. When I disable the font-lock-mode, everything becomes fine (blue text is not blue anymore, +/- lines are colored).

I could add hooks to disable font-lock-mode in those buffers but it is too much trouble to do that for every buffer. Can I somehow find out what causes the screwup in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out that I created a problem myself. I unconditionally enabled 
[rainbow-mode](https://julien.danjou.info/projects/emacs-packages) in all buffers, which sets the `font-lock-keywords` variable.

To discover this I debugged the `font-lock-specified-p` function which returned `t` in Magit mode (and it shouldn't). Hope this information helps someone.