# highlight-chars and magit is conflicting

Tags: magit, font-lock, highlight-chars

first time StackExchange user here.

I'm having trouble with highlight-chars (probably font-lock) and magit.
Enabling hc-toggle-highlight-* functions will remove the coloring from magit buffers.

[image]

Possibly duplicate:
[Font-lock for strings messes up non-code buffers](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/13568/font-lock-for-strings-messes-up-non-code-buffers)

Anyone else have this trouble, or know some possible workaround?

Minimum .emacs:

```
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
         '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/"))
(package-initialize)

(require 'magit) ;; Current version 20160210.555
(require 'highlight-chars) ;; Current version 20151231.1335

;; (hc-toggle-highlight-tabs t)
;; (hc-toggle-highlight-trailing-whitespace t)
(add-hook 'font-lock-mode-hook 'hc-highlight-tabs)
(add-hook 'font-lock-mode-hook 'hc-highlight-trailing-whitespace)
```

Comment: I've seen this happen when enabling `whitespace-mode` in a magit buffer. Never got around to investigating further though.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to look at the Magit code to see what it is doing. You don't say what highlighting Magit does normally, and just what changes when [`highlight-chars.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/highlight-chars.el) ([Highlight Library](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HighlightLibrary)) is added to the mix. I don't use Magit -- maybe someone else can speak to this.

But `highlight-chars.el` does add to `font-lock-keywords` for things like highlighting tabs and trailing whitespace. It's possible that this interferes with the font-lock keywords used by Magit.

However, user option **`hc-font-lock-override`** controls whether the current highlighting face used by `hc-*` commands overrides (`t`), is overridden by (`keep`), or merges with (`append` or `prepend`) any existing highlighting.

You should thus be able to make `hc-*` highlighting cohabit well with other text-property highlighting - you can control which highlighting of a given piece of text, highlighting by `hc-*` or highlighting by some other code, has precedence, and how much it dominates the other highlighting.

E.g., you can set the value of `hc-font-lock-override` to `keep` (e.g., using `M-x customize-option hc-font-lock-override`), to prevent `hc-*` highlighting from overwriting any already existing highlighting.

See also options `hc-other-chars` and `hc-other-chars-NOT`, which control which chars are governed by `hc-toggle-highlight-other-chars`.

You might also try changing the order (i.e., when you turn on the `hc-*` highlighting). `hc-highlight-trailing-whitespace` and `hc-highlight-tabs` just add patterns to match at the *end* of `font-lock-keywords`.

However, be aware that highlighting from *text properties* (e.g. `face` or `font-lock-face`) always has less precedence than highlighting from *overlays*.  Library `highlight-chars.el` uses text-property highlighting, as does all use of font-lock. If some other library uses overlay highlighting on the same text area then the overlay highlighting wins in case of conflict - always.

---

[2018-04-07: I updated `highlight-chars.el` to let option `hc-font-lock-override` (previously called `hc-other-chars-font-lock-override`) control all `hc-*` highlighting, not just other-char highlighting.]

Comment: Good idea, but unfortunately it did not solve the problem. I started digging in the magit code, and especially the `magit-section-make-overlay` function. My newest hypothesis is that `font-lock` conflicts with `overlay-put` from the built in buffer.c.

Comment: Overlay properties always override text properties. `highlight-chars.el` uses font-lock, which, yes, uses text properties. If Magit uses overlays then they should take precedence. If its overlays use property `face` then that face should be seen, not a face used by `highlight-chars.el`. But it sounds like you are seeing the opposite (you said that h-c breaks Magit, not the other way around).

Comment: What makes you think that Magit is using overlays at the locations where h-c is trying to highlight? Glancing at some of the code, I see that the overlay is used for `magit-section-highlight` and `magit-section-highlight-selection`. What happens if you remove those from option `magit-section-highlight-hook`, as a test? That presumably will take overlays out of the equation.